# SQL queries from database with Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm using Laravel and trying to do an SQL query from my Controller in a public function, but I'm really confused where I would put my table in the argument and if quotes go around the argument. Here is my code

```
 public function selectMethod(){
    $results = DB::select('select firstname from people where id = 1');
    print_r($results);
    return view('pages.selectMethod');
}
```

table is called people

My .env is configured to my database correctly and I get this error

FatalErrorException in AboutController.php line 90:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found

Thanks !

Comment: Only add ----use DB;---- namespace

Comment: use \DB instead of DB

Answer (score 1):

you should add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`
at the top of your page
for example :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show a list of all of the application's users.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->get();

        return view('user.index', ['users' => $users]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error clearly states: *Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found*

Hence just *use* DB in your class. Add:

```
use DB;
```

At the top of the file just below the namespace line.

Also, I would suggest you to use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) for your queries. It will make your life a lot easier and your code a lot beautiful.